# subtract one image from another using openCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, subtraction

How can I subtract one image from another using openCV?

Ps.: I coudn't use the python implementation because I'll have to do it in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LoadImage` to load your images into memory, then use the [Sub](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/operations_on_arrays.html#sub) method.

This link contains some example code, if that will help: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.opencv/36167

Comment: This answer was born outdated :) [DatChu answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2549246/2436175) is the only valid nowadays.

Comment: The first link times out, second link is dead.

Comment: Yeah... link answers. eish.

Answer (score 19):

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

Mat im = imread("cameraman.tif");
Mat im2 = imread("lena.tif");

Mat diff_im = im - im2;
```

Change the image names. Also make sure they have the same size.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using `diff` or just plain subtraction `im1-im2` I would rather suggest the OpenCV method `cv::absdiff`

```
using namespace cv;
Mat im1 = imread("image1.jpg");
Mat im2 = imread("image2.jpg");
Mat diff;
absdiff(im1, im2, diff);
```

Since images are usually stored using unsigned formats, the subtraction methods of @Dat and @ssh99 will kill all the negative differences. For example, if some pixel of a BMP image has value `[20, 50, 30]` for `im1` and `[70, 80, 90]` for `im2`, using both `im1 - im2` and `diff(im1, im2, diff)` will produce value `[0,0,0]`, since `20-70 = -50`, `50-80 = -30`, `30-90 = -60` and all negative results will be converted to unsigned value of `0`, which, in most cases, is not what you want. Method `absdiff` will instead calculate the absolute values of all subtractions, thus producing more reasonable `[50,30,60]`.

Answer (score 6):

use cv::subtract() method.

```
Mat img1=some_img;
Mat img2=some_img;

Mat dest;

cv::subtract(img1,img2,dest);
```

This performs elementwise subtract of (img1-img2). 
you can find more details about it http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html