# How to find correlation between frames of a video using Opencv?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, video-processing

I want to segregate the frames that have high correlation.
Suppose in a video the first 6 seconds, the scenes do not change much except that there is a very little movement of objects. How can I separate out those frames by finding the correlation between all of them. ....

For this I visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998195/how-to-find-the-differences-between-frames-using-opencv) link but it did not help much ....

Please help me in this problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will assume that a keyframe is a frame presenting content a lot
>   different from the previous ones (it's not a formal definition, but it
>   fits). Take frames i and i+1. Use cv2.absDiff to compute the
>   difference between the frames and cv2.sumElems to get the sum of all
>   pixels differences. Do this for all frames i. This will reduce your
>   video stream to an one dimensional signal. Look for peaks in this
>   signal and pick keyframes corresponding to these peaks.

found here: [Key Frame Extraction From Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064962/key-frame-extraction-from-video/9079148#comment12142577_9079148)

Comment: A peak is a indicator of "a big change" in the video stream, so you have to look between those peeks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [image subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501957/subtract-one-image-from-another-using-opencv). [Cross-correlation](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/correlate/) is also acceptable here.

Google search phrase: `background subtraction algorithm`.

Also [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) contains needed info for you.